# Trying to reduce the levels of the categorical variable I want to predict (on R)

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, classification, multiclass-classification

I am working on a classification task with a categorical dependent variable with 99 levels (each corresponding to a country)

I am using a decision tree, and it looks like I cannot have more than 32 levels so that I need to reduce the number of levels. I was thinking to cluster countries by similarity such that the ones that are similar based on the 200 variables I have (v1, v2, v3...), would be grouped.

I was thinking of using UMAP in order to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset and then group the countries together (for instance Norway+Sweden, Laos+Cambodia or whatever) but I am having some hard times doing so, here is what I have so far ( working on a subsample), I tried to plot it but it doesn't much sense to me

```
data = sample_n(surveydata, 15000)
cluster.data = data[, grep("v", colnames(surveydata))]
library(umap)

data.umap = umap(cluster.data)
plot(data.umap$layout, col=data$Nationality)
```

(Nationality is the cathegorical variables with 99 levels I have to predict)

do you know any method I can use to reduce the levels to less than 32?

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: My stats isn't(aren't?) the best, why not use PCA?

Comment: Have you thought about using one-hot / dummy variables? That way you can keep all the levels you need.

Comment: Since you do not show your data, it is hard to make solid suggestions. But I like your idea of clustering. Depending on what variables you have in your data,  you might try clustering on some of the independent variables that are meaningful for your problem. E.g. Cluster on population, GNP, Life expectancy, infant mortality, etc.